# Is this so bad when using MySQL queries in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update a lot of rows, per a user request. It is a site with products.

I could...

- Delete all old rows for that product, then loop through string building a new `INSERT` query. This however will lose all data if the `INSERT` fails.
- Perform an `UPDATE` through each loop. This loop currently iterates over 8 items, but in the future it may get up to 15. This many `UPDATE`s doesn't sound like too good an idea.
- Change DB Schema, and add an `auto_increment` Id to the rows. Then first do a `SELECT`, get all *old rows* ids in a variable, perform one `INSERT`, and then a `DELETE WHERE IN SET`.

What is the usual practice here?

Thanks

Comment: This probably doesn't have anything to do with PHP. It's more of a design issue. I think you need to take a step back and a fresg look at what you're trying to do. Go make yourself a cup of tea... :)

Comment: I just added the PHP tag because I mentioned loops etc. Might be helpful for background. Also, I'm not a tea / coffee drinker. Perhaps I should be!

Comment: If you want to consolidate bulk updates, you can INSERT a key:value map into a temporary table, and then UPDATE your target table JOINing the temporary table.  But for 8-15 updates, this is probably a waste of effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the updates. In a transaction if you need to. 15 updates is peanuts, unless you're doing it on every page access or something.

You don't want to be deleting/re-inserting rows just to avoid extra queries. And you won't be able to, if you ever want to have a foreign key referencing the table you're updating.

Almost certainly a premature optimisation.

Comment: Thanks bobince. The *premature optimisation* thing did jump out at me, however an `UPDATE` in a loop also triggered my *Maybe there is a better way?*

Comment: As long as it's an actual loop that performs 15 updates, and not you writing out by hand 15 different update statements.

Answer (score 2):

15 `UPDATE`s is really not all that many. If you were talking about 15 *hundred* then perhaps you'd have to think about your design a bit more...

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is probably to use stored procedures.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines.html
It would be only one command on PHP side. The rest would be implemented on MySQL sever.

You can also try to execute few queries at once using mysqli::multi-query.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php